# Can't access window/global variable – seems it isn't defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

### The goal

Access `window.MyApp`.

### The problem

If I do `console.log(window)`, `MyApp` object appears there; if I do  `console.log(window.MyApp)`, console throws me:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MyApp is not defined

### Going further

I'm using Ruby (v 2.1.2) on Rails (v 4.0.1) with Backbone (v 1.1.2) and Asset Pipeline. My environment is as follow:

`/app/assets/javascripts/backbone/myapp.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require_tree ./templates
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./views
//= require_tree ./routers

window.MyApp = {
  Models: {},
  Collections: {},
  Routers: {},
  Views: {}
};
```

In `/app/assets/javascripts/backbone/routers/my_router.js` – where the error happens –, there's the following:

```
console.log(MyApp);
```

In `/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`, I'm invoking the  `/app/assets/javascripts/backbone/myapp.js` this way:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- lots of stuff here -->
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'backbone/myapp' %>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- lots of other stuffs here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you attempting to log _before_ or _after_ the definition?

Comment: According to the Asset Pipeline's requires, it seems to be logging *before* the definition. The problem is: why then appears `MyApp` object when I just log `window` variable? Sounds strange. Anyway, basically everything was generated by [backbone-rails](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails) gem's scaffolding – maybe an issue?

Comment: Have you done this `var MyApp = window.MyApp || {};` before logging to console? And remove `var` for console testing.

Comment: It printed `Object {}`, @hex494D49. I didn't think to make this debugging case – I'm having a better understanding of the problem now. The problem itself is not solved, still trying. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if it happens to global objects but the declaration could be getting hoisted.  If you move the declaration MyApp declaration above the requires or to a different file and require it before you the other backbone items it should fix it.